# How to setup test data for TestNG Java

Tags: java, testng, integration-testing

There are some tests that need the data in the database in some state. For now I am using the **@BeforeMethod** Annotation to setup the data.  The problem that I face is duplication of the same setup in every test class. 
What is the correct approach for the problem? Should I add an abstract class ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have N number of test classes that are dependent on each other, then use a @BeforeSuite method for setting up data. Use **testNGxml** to call this class (Which has @BeforeSuite method) *firstly*.

If you have independent test classes then use @BeforeClass method to setup data before each test class is executed.